# Tests in Laravel not picking up collection attributes

Tags: php, laravel

I have a test in Laravel 7 constructed as follows:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;

class LoginControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    /**
     * A basic feature test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testLoginPractitioner()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class, 1)->make();

        dump($user);

        $response = $this->post('/api/login', [
            'phone_number' => $user->phone_number,
            'password' => $user->password
        ], [
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
            'Content_Type' => 'application/json'
        ]);

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('users', [
            'phone_number' => $user->phone_number,
        ]);
    }
}
```

With the user factory defined as this:

```
$factory->define(User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
return [
    'email' => $faker->unique()->safeEmail,
    'email_verified_at' => now(),
    'phone_number' => '12' . $faker->numerify('#########'),
    'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi',
    'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
    'is_admin' => false
];
```

});

When I dump the user object created in the test, I can see that it has a phone_number attribute:

```
#attributes: array:6 [
    "email" => "leonora.tromp@example.com"
    "email_verified_at" => "2021-01-31 11:25:02"
    "phone_number" => "12326385883"
    "password" => "$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi"
    "remember_token" => "Oy8DfAonMu"
    "is_admin" => false
  ]
```

But my test keeps failing and I get this message, as if it has not phone_number attribute:

```
1) Tests\Feature\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginControllerTest::testLoginPractitioner
Exception: Property [phone_number] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

Additionally, the assert fails even if I use a number that I am sure is in the database. Why is this happening?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63055726/laravel-assertdatabasehas-in-phpunit-test-is-not-working

Comment: `make()` doesn't insert to the database. `create()` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is `$user` is a `Collection`, when you give a `factory` an amount of models to create, it will return a `Collection` instance contained the models created in your case 1. Secondly for the model to be saved to the db you should call `create()` and not `make()`.

Changing the user creation code to the following should solve the problem.

```
$user = factory(User::class)->create();
```

If you at a time need to create multiple users, you need to get them out of the `Collection`. As you seem confused about `Collections`, probably reading up on [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections) would be wise.